Account - what happens to default record type when Person Accounts are enabled
I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but maybe someone here knows.
In Apex Tests we were relying on default Account RecordTypeId values for validations in Services, but after enabling Person Account RecordTypeId is now null instead of the first available record type.
Does someone know the reason for it?
I'm not sure if it's related but having access/no access to the Person Account record type has no effect on the outcome.

What is the default Record Type of Person Account SObject?
If it is Person Account then is PersonAccount.PersonAccount RecordType added to Permission Set / Profile via <recordTypeVisibilities>? Try to add it.

Yes, I tried adding Account.PersonAccount record type and granting access to it (as mentioned in the third paragraph), but it didn't help. That's why I also got confused

From the PA impl guide: When person accounts are enabled, a default person account record type is automatically created. And since Person Account is syntactic sugar with Account as the underlying type, if you had no defined record types in Account and were relying on default RT, the default is gone when you turn on PA. The impl guide tells you to prepare for this: Create at least one record type for business accounts. Salesforce creates a record type for person accounts when they’re enabled.

there were already 5 business accounts records types in use, logic was relying on one of those

were relying on default Account RecordTypeId value - which one is it that your test code was expecting - the default or one of the 5 business account record types?

it was one of the five that Users have access to

Turning on PA does not impact custom Account record types. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

that's what I thought too, I'll try to setup example on scratch orgs if I have time today
